# Local variable in Python

Tags: python, global

I am an amateur in learing programming in Python. Recently, I found a question on local variable for functions. Here is my sample code:

```
"""
Scenario-1:
"""
a=4

def g(x):
    #global a
    #a=a+2
    print(a)
    return x+a
```

when I type `g(2)` in console (I am using Enthought Canopy), it returns:

```
4
6
```

----nothing wrong.
then I change the code to (delete `"#"` before `"a=a+2")`:

```
"""
Scenario-2:
"""
a=4

def g(x):
    #global a
    a=a+2
    print(a)
    return x+a
```

then re-run the code and type `g(2)`, it shows:

```
*UnboundLocalError: local variable 'a' referenced before assignment*
```

My 1st question is: in Scenario-1, as I return `x+a`, why there is no *referenced before assignment* error?

Additionally, I change the code to:

```
"""
Scenario-3:
"""
a=4

def g(x):
    global a
    a=a+2
    print(a)
    return x+a
```

then I re-run the code and type `g(2)`, it returns:

```
6
8
```

----nothing wrong. BUT, when I type a and enter in console, it returns:

```
4
```

Here comes my 2nd question, on global variable:

as I declare a to be global in function g(x), why variable a did not change to 6=4+2 (according to a=a+2)? I thought when variable a is so-called "global", the value changing in function inside will lead to the changing outside of the function, which is in main(). Am I wrong?

Above are my two basic questions. Thank you very much!

Comment: Thank you for @sapam editing my texts and code! I must make it by myself next time

Comment: *Binding* determines the scope. Assignment is a form of binding; because you assign to `a` in `g()` it is determined to be a local. Other actions that bind are imports (using `import x` inside a function makes `x` a local), using a name as a target in `for`, or `except <exception> as name` or `with cm as name`, and more.

Comment: Override the default by using the `global` statement. `global a` anywhere in `g()` will make `a` global again even though you bound to it.

Comment: Last but not least, you have no `main()` in your function. `a` is a global, you assigned a new value to the global.

Answer (score 0):

(1) You may reference a global variable without declaring it.  However, Python requires the **global** declaration if you want to *assign* the value.